# How can I deploy HTML along with a WAR with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7, maven-3

I have one Java project which works flawlessly with Maven.  It builds a WAR, drops it into a Tomcat container, boom.  Services work awesome.

Now I'd like to deploy the HTML UI in the same way.  It's a separate project in source control, so I assume I'd have to add it as some sort of dependency.  Can I somehow package that project into the WAR along with the Java so that it gets extracted out?  Or at least have Maven drop it into the appropriate `webapp` directory if necessary?

Or, am I forced to use a different build tool and have a separate step in by build/deployment process?

Comment: I believe you can add a maven module in to reference the HTML files in the other project.   I would look into modules in the maven documentation

Comment: Why would you like to separate the HTML code from the WAR module?

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't want to separate it from the final WAR.  But they are separate projects in source control, which is appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `maven-war-plugin` supports so-called [overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html), i.e. archives of web resources as separate artifacts to be included into the WAR under construction.

If that does not fit your needs, you can always define additional [webResources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) and use `maven-dependency-plugin` or `maven-antrun-plugin` to copy these resources from their original location to the addtional resource folder in your current project.

Comment: Interesting.  It looks like the resource either has to be a Maven artifact or on the local filesystem, though.  Is that correct?

Comment: Overlays always have to be artifacts.

Comment: The `webResources` bit worked nicely.  I'd prefer not to have the project referenced on the file system and to pull it down from somewhere, but this works for now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the same maven tool. In a war file keep the html files where the JSP's are kept. You do not need to do anything else.

Comment: I think the OP is asking because the HTML files are in a separate project.

Comment: I think he can create a seperate war project.

Comment: Not if we wants to pack that separate project into the same WAR along with his Java project (that's what the question is about)